# How to create a repeating pattern from the previously designed pattern?

Tags: patterns, swatches

I know the steps in how to properly create a custom pattern by creating a square with various color and shape differences. However, I found the hexagon repeating pattern from a movie and I much rather how best to crop the hexagon so that it will tile properly.

This is the pattern that I would like to re-create for my swatches.[image]

Comment: Simply define an area which repeats. Because of that gradient vignette, you should simply select two hexagons in the center of the image.

Comment: Should I cut off the border on each side of the hexagon so it would really be four hexagons inside a Square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply want to encompass an area which repeats.....

Here's how I'd define the pattern - the white area would define a repeatable tile (this is loose and rough, it would need some pixel precision refinement):

[image]

Comment: Ok, That helps. I thought I needed to cut the border.